# Rails Many-to-Many with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model called service_request which `belongs_to :unit` and `belongs_to :user`

the User and Unit model both are setup with `has_many :service_requests`

There is another model called Tenant where a user has to exist in order to be allowed to create the service request.  So I'm looking up the current_users email to see if they are in the Tenant table.

So the service_requests table is a join table which has a foreign key for a user and a second foreign key for a unit, plus additional columns specific just to the service request itself.

The issue is that I need to save 3 things the user, unit, and whatever is passed in for the service request columns too.  Currently I can save a service request that has the user and unit but I am not sure how to pass in the strong parameters for the service request as well `service_request_params`

in the service_requests controller I have a create action

```
  def create
      # check to see that the user exists in the tenant table first
    if Tenant.exists?(email: current_user.email) 

      @tenant ||= Tenant.find_by(email: current_user.email) if current_user 
        @tenant.unit  # find the tenants unit object

      # create service_request and pass the user and tenant unit info
      @service_request = ServiceRequest.new(unit: @tenant.unit, user: current_user)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @service_request.save
          format.html { redirect_to @service_request, notice: 'Service request successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service_request }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @service_request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end

      else
         # [ TODO: handle when the user is not in tenant table]

        end  
      end 




  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def service_request_params
      params.require(:service_request).permit(:title)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it working, not sure if this is the preferred "Rails way", if it's not please let me know.

In the create action I just called the strong params and then used .merge to add on the additional unit and user data.

```
  @service_request = ServiceRequest.new(service_request_params.merge(unit: @tenant.unit, user: current_user))
```

Comment: You could also do `@service_request.unit = @tentant.unit` and `@service_request.user = current_user`.